# convert the api return datetime string from 24 format to 12 hour format in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have a datetime like below

```
17/05/2018 23:59:00 PM
```

It is storing in database like varchar(100).
I want to convert this as 17/05/2018 11:59:00 PM.
It is returning from the api.I have tried to fix tried so many ways.
somehow it is working but coming tomorrow date like it is giving now like this

18/05/2018 11:59 AM

.Is any efficient way to do this.

```
 $startdate='17/05/2018 23:59:00 PM';
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i A',$startdate);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('d/m/Y h:i A');
echo $newDateString;
```

Comment: You forgot to account for seconds `d/m/Y H:i:s A`

Comment: if i added d/m/Y H:i:s A nothing changed

Comment: Why are you storing dates in DB like varchar in the first place? Get a date model in there to start with

Comment: I want that 24 hour fomat to 12 hour format .that is my question

Comment: Actually when I remove the last characters AM and try to convert the datetime to 12 hour format  it is giving empty Y don't I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using AM/PM and 24 hour format. That doesn't make sense. PHP is probably trying its best to make sense of it and adding 12 hours to the datetime pushing it to the next day.

If you ignore the PM from your datetime this works just fine:

```
$startdate='17/05/2018 23:59:00 PM';
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s+',$startdate);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('d/m/Y h:i:s A');
echo $newDateString;
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/996675)

Comment: my datetime coming from the api when used  var_dump it is giving string 22 how can i change that to work it

Comment: It's just a string so you can use remove the last three characters any way you want. `substr()`, `rtrim()`, etc.

Comment: @itsme Updated my answer to deal with the AM/PM issue

Comment: Thanks for your help .Now i fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would save the timestamp to the dB rather than the actual date

```
$startDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '17/05/2018 23:59:00');
$timeStamp = $startDateTime->getTimeStamp();

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($timeStamp);

echo $date->format('d/m/Y h:i:s A');
```